# Does AS3 buffer files that are supposed to be gotten from the web?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, buffer

I've got code that can either load graphics from the computer or grab it from the web.

```
if (URL == "computer")
    fileAddress = "images/" + fileName;
else
    fileAddress = "http://safe-xchange.com//" + URL + "//pics//" + fileName;

graphic = new Loader();
graphic.load(new URLRequest(fileAddress));
graphic.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, GraphicLoaded);
graphic.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, OnIOError);

graphic.x = x;
graphic.y = y;
```

I put together an EXE using swf-to-exe.com.  It loads almost all of the graphics, but there are a few that it does not load.  When I run the program using FlashDevelop everything works fine.

So I started playing around using FlashDevelop, and found that if I changed the file name on the web it still shows up! AS3 seems to be doing some buffering here.  I ran across that before with music files- it seemed to load the wrong file, finally I changed the name and it loaded it correctly.

Is there a way to block that buffering?

Comment: Never mind- found out the problem...

Comment: On SO it is actually encouraged to answer your own question if you find the solution. Please, answer your question and accept it as the correct answer after two days, so others having similar problems will benefit from your insight, just like you have intended to benefit of other programmers insight. We must help each-other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's quite simple. For most of the graphics I was checking to see if they were loaded. There were a few small graphics that I was not checking, and that worked just fine when using FlashDevelop. It did not work with an EXE file.  I added code to make sure all the graphics were loaded and bingo, it was all good.

I'm still wondering why the music files didn't work- I was checking to see if they were loaded.